# linux shell, keep task alive for specified time

Tags: linux, shell, scheduled-tasks, reboot

I am looking for a tool to keep a task alive (restarting if necessary) for a specified amount of time (in seconds), and then kill it and stop. For example: `keep_for 3600 rsync foo bar:faz` should for try to synchronize a directory (restarting rsync in case of f.e. dropped connection), but explicitly kill rsync and stop respawning it after an hour.

I tried to write a shell script for that, but it was surprisingly difficult to write, with lots of edge cases (like child process not getting killed, or shell escaping issues). So... maybe there already is a tool for that?

Answer (score 3):

If your system has [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), you can create an [events](http://linux.die.net/man/5/events) file for your script/command and this *may* do what you want (if not now then possibly in a future version using [planned features](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/faq.html)).

Here are a few bits of information from the `events(5)` man page:

- Manual start:

  > start on <event>
  >   Describes on what condition to start this job. Without this
  >   section, the job can only be manually started with the
  >   initctl(8) command.
- Respawn:

  > respawn
  >   This sets the daemon, service, and respawn flags for the job.
  >   The respawn flag means that the process will be restarted when
  >   it ends
- Respawn limit:

  > respawn limit [count [timeout]]
  >   This configures respawn limits. Respawn limits only apply
  >   if the respawn flag is set for the job; setting a limit
  >   does not automatically set respawning capability. If the
  >   process is respawned more than count times within an
  >   interval of timeout seconds, the job will be stopped
  >   automatically, and not restarted. The limit defaults to 10
  >   times within 5 seconds.

See [Getting Started](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).

Comment: If I understand the manual correctly, this is a planned feature... also I think that for an ad-hoc command it is slightly too big :-) Still, thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate the tasks, keeping them in the same script (I thought of this as a C program, but it should be doable as a script).

I'd start with a background subprocess timer to send a signal at the timeout.  The signal handler shuts everything down cleanly and exits.

Then start a loop that respawns the desired command whenever it exits without a success (zero) status.

Trying to keep track of both the timeout and the command in one loop will get excessively complex.

Comment: If I wanted to write a script, I'd ask on stackoverflow. Here I am just looking for a ready solution.

Answer (score -1):

This question is posed in terms of an implementation. I suggest you re-frame it in terms of what you are trying to accomplish which may yield a more obvious (and elegant) solution.

Comment: I am looking for a generic robust tool to respawn a process for a given time, and then to forcefully stop it after some time. Downloading/uploading a file and playing internet radio using mplayer are my usual use cases, but I often have different tasks that have to be performed in a specific time window. Both `rsync` and `mplayer` stop when there's connection break, so I want them to be restarted. That's all.