# Run a script in Linux for a specified amount of time before stopping and restarting

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks

Possibly related to this [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/138882/linux-shell-keep-task-alive-for-specified-time), I would like to be able to run a task for a specified amount of time, then stop/kill it, then start it again.

Specifically, I run the Folding@Home application on my Linux workstation. Periodically, it will have trouble logging-in to the home server, and will sit idle for a long time, but not release memory/resources it has claimed (yes, I realize this is likely a bug in the tool, but I can't fix that currently). Typically just the act of killing and starting the tool will allow it to check-in again.

So, I would like to be able to run something like:

```
run_for <time> ./fah6
```

Does such a tool exist, or should I write a wrapper than nukes the `fah6` client after, say, a week and restart it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be old school, but this sounds like a job for cron.  Just kill / restart it with cron on some appropriate schedule.  You'll have to take into account if fah6 can "pick up where it left off" easily, but I don't see any problem with a daily restart.

Hotei

Comment: it does pick up where it left off .. and I had not considered using `cron` for this one :) .. I'll see how hard that may be to do

Comment: I like this idea. You could use two cron jobs to help ensure that it runs only during non-work hours -- one that does `killall fah6` at 9:00 am and another that starts it up again at 6:00 pm.

Comment: this has turned out to be a very usable suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

timeout tool.

> timeout - run a command with a time limit
>
> timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
>   timeout [OPTION]
>
> Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

for example:

```
    timeout 15s ./fah6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sleep 60 & VAR=$! ; sleep 10 ; kill $VAR
```

In this example, '**sleep 60**' is a placeholder for the command you want to terminate early.  Replace '**10**' with how long you want to run your timed command (at most) in seconds.  The above should exit after 10 seconds, killing the '**sleep 60**' process.

Note that this is for bash.

Comment: Thanx! This simple solution ultimately does the job!

Answer (score 1):

`cron` will work, but if you only wanted it run once, or if the time will change from day to day then it would be simpler to use `at` ([at man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/at.1posix.html)):

```
$ ./fah6 &
[1] 12345
$ at 1800
at> kill 12345
at> <EOT>
```

The steps are:

- start fah6 as a background job (the `&` at the end of the line starts it as a background job). The next line reports the process number
- at is followed by the time to end the job
- the `at>` prompt appears, type kill and the job number reported above
- to stop entering commands, quit by pressing Ctrl-D

Comment: how would I know the process number if I want to do this in an unattended fashion?

Comment: @warren, you can use `$!`, as in slartibartfast's answer

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I would implement this within the script the capability of running, waiting and killing the subprocess.

In python with something like:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html

If it's not in Pyton, use os.system('./fah6') in the code of the script that handle wait/stop/restart